# Test boundary: Check if a function calls another function or check the outcome of this another function

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am writing unit tests for a function. Depending on the input, the function will call some other functions.

I can verify the expected behavior by

1. Mock the called functions and check if they are called (or not called) with the expected arguments
2. Or check the outcome of these other functions

I prefer #1 because I believe the outcome of these other functions should be tested in their own corresponding tests. But my colleagues prefers #2.

Can someone help me with the principles that govern this?

Comment: My question is, how you wanna mock other functions(if they don't belongs to any struct)?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 isn't out of the question if the outcomes themselves are difficult to test. But option 2 is preferable. Why?

Because option 1 tests implementation details. This in turn locks down those details.

Option 2 is ignorant of the implementation. This supports changing the design.

If you're able to test the outcomes, there's no need to write tests for each unit. If we grew the solution with TDD, the production code might start as a larger function. Each refactoring would be supported by the tests. Maybe we'd extract other functions. Maybe we'd extract entire classes. Who can say? With TDD, we can defer those decisions. We can even change our minds.